# SYN flood on mysql server

Tags: linux, networking, mysql

Consider this structure:

`DB <-TCP3306- WEB{1,2,3,4}`

All servers are CentOS 6/7
Web servers are running PHP (using `php-fpm`) that connects to the MySQL server.
Occasionally, I get this error message on the PHP side:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104
```

And this on the DB server:

```
possible SYN flooding on port 3306. Sending cookies.
```

My current theory is that the web servers are are opening too many sockets, filling up the DB server's network stack with new sockets faster than MySQL can `accept` them.
I tried modifying the following values:

- net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog
- net.core.somaxconn
- net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse

But no avail.
I'm not sure how I can even confirm my pending socket theory, or solve this situation. Any avail?

---

Below is my `sysctl -a | grep ^net` on DB:

```
net.netfilter.nf_log.0 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.1 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.2 = nfnetlink_log
net.netfilter.nf_log.3 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.4 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.5 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.6 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.7 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.8 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.9 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.10 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.11 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.12 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmpv6_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events_retry_timeout = 15
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 500000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 25048
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets = 16384
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_checksum = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_expect_max = 256
net.core.somaxconn = 5000
net.core.xfrm_aevent_etime = 10
net.core.xfrm_aevent_rseqth = 2
net.core.xfrm_larval_drop = 1
net.core.xfrm_acq_expires = 30
net.core.wmem_max = 124928
net.core.rmem_max = 124928
net.core.wmem_default = 124928
net.core.rmem_default = 124928
net.core.dev_weight = 64
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 1000
net.core.netdev_rss_key = 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
net.core.message_cost = 5
net.core.message_burst = 10
net.core.optmem_max = 20480
net.core.rps_sock_flow_entries = 0
net.core.busy_poll = 0
net.core.busy_read = 0
net.core.netdev_budget = 300
net.core.warnings = 1
net.ipv4.route.gc_thresh = 524288
net.ipv4.route.max_size = 8388608
net.ipv4.route.gc_min_interval = 0
net.ipv4.route.gc_min_interval_ms = 500
net.ipv4.route.gc_timeout = 300
net.ipv4.route.gc_interval = 60
net.ipv4.route.redirect_load = 20
net.ipv4.route.redirect_number = 9
net.ipv4.route.redirect_silence = 20480
net.ipv4.route.error_cost = 1000
net.ipv4.route.error_burst = 5000
net.ipv4.route.gc_elasticity = 8
net.ipv4.route.mtu_expires = 600
net.ipv4.route.min_pmtu = 552
net.ipv4.route.min_adv_mss = 256
net.ipv4.route.secret_interval = 600
net.ipv4.neigh.default.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.default.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.default.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.default.retrans_time = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.default.base_reachable_time = 30
net.ipv4.neigh.default.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.default.unres_qlen = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.default.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.default.anycast_delay = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.default.proxy_delay = 79
net.ipv4.neigh.default.locktime = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.default.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.default.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 128
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 512
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 1024
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.retrans_time = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.base_reachable_time = 30
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.unres_qlen = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.anycast_delay = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.proxy_delay = 79
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.locktime = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.retrans_time = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.base_reachable_time = 30
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.unres_qlen = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.anycast_delay = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.proxy_delay = 79
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.locktime = 99
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.eth0.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_retrans_collapse = 1
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 64
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 262144
net.ipv4.ip_dynaddr = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
net.ipv4.tcp_retries1 = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_abort_on_overflow = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_stdurg = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 16384
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000
net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports = 
net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships = 20
net.ipv4.igmp_max_msf = 10
net.ipv4.inet_peer_threshold = 65664
net.ipv4.inet_peer_minttl = 120
net.ipv4.inet_peer_maxttl = 600
net.ipv4.inet_peer_gc_mintime = 10
net.ipv4.inet_peer_gc_maxtime = 120
net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_fack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_reordering = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_dsack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 1529376  2039168 3058752
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096    16384   4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096    87380   4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_app_win = 31
net.ipv4.tcp_adv_win_scale = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_frto = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_frto_response = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tso_win_divisor = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
net.ipv4.tcp_abc = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_base_mss = 512
net.ipv4.tcp_workaround_signed_windows = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit = 100
net.ipv4.tcp_limit_output_bytes = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_dma_copybreak = 4096
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 1
net.ipv4.cipso_cache_enable = 1
net.ipv4.cipso_cache_bucket_size = 10
net.ipv4.cipso_rbm_optfmt = 0
net.ipv4.cipso_rbm_strictvalid = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control = cubic reno
net.ipv4.tcp_allowed_congestion_control = cubic reno
net.ipv4.tcp_max_ssthresh = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_thin_linear_timeouts = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_thin_dupack = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_min_tso_segs = 2
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 1529376  2039168 3058752
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 4096
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 4096
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.disable_xfrm = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.disable_policy = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.tag = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.xfrm4_gc_thresh = 4194304
net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 4194304
net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 3145728
net.ipv4.ipfrag_time = 30
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_errors_use_inbound_ifaddr = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_ratelimit = 1000
net.ipv4.icmp_ratemask = 6168
net.ipv4.rt_cache_rebuild_count = 4
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 1   0
net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward_use_pmtu = 0
net.ipv4.ipfrag_secret_interval = 600
net.ipv4.ipfrag_max_dist = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.default.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.default.unres_qlen = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.default.anycast_delay = 99
net.ipv6.neigh.default.proxy_delay = 79
net.ipv6.neigh.default.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 128
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 512
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 1024
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.unres_qlen = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.anycast_delay = 99
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.proxy_delay = 79
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.unres_qlen = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.anycast_delay = 99
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.proxy_delay = 79
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.xfrm6_gc_thresh = 2048
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.all.mtu = 1280
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitations = 3
net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.all.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.all.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.all.regen_max_retry = 5
net.ipv6.conf.all.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.all.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.optimistic_dad = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.default.mtu = 1280
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.router_solicitations = 3
net.ipv6.conf.default.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.default.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.default.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.default.regen_max_retry = 5
net.ipv6.conf.default.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.default.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.optimistic_dad = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mtu = 65536
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.router_solicitations = 3
net.ipv6.conf.lo.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.lo.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_tempaddr = -1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.lo.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.lo.regen_max_retry = 5
net.ipv6.conf.lo.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.lo.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.optimistic_dad = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_dad = -1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mtu = 9001
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitations = 3
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.regen_max_retry = 5
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.optimistic_dad = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.ip6frag_high_thresh = 4194304
net.ipv6.ip6frag_low_thresh = 3145728
net.ipv6.ip6frag_time = 60
net.ipv6.route.gc_thresh = 1024
net.ipv6.route.max_size = 16384
net.ipv6.route.gc_min_interval = 0
net.ipv6.route.gc_timeout = 60
net.ipv6.route.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv6.route.gc_elasticity = 0
net.ipv6.route.mtu_expires = 600
net.ipv6.route.min_adv_mss = 1
net.ipv6.route.gc_min_interval_ms = 500
net.ipv6.icmp.ratelimit = 1000
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
net.ipv6.nf_conntrack_frag6_timeout = 60
net.ipv6.nf_conntrack_frag6_low_thresh = 3145728
net.ipv6.nf_conntrack_frag6_high_thresh = 4194304
net.ipv6.ip6frag_secret_interval = 600
net.ipv6.mld_max_msf = 64
net.nf_conntrack_max = 500000
net.unix.max_dgram_qlen = 10
```